# TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this._setComponentRef.bind')

Tags: react-native, expo

i keep getting this error every time i try to run the project. I tried many other solutions/fixes, but no success.

it is so weird as i didnt update/install any new dependencies on the project. The only thing i remember is restarting my machine yesterday, then this happen. i feel it has something to do with babel.

The last time i work on it, no error came out. But it just showing this red screen when i tried to continue where i left off last week. I have reset cache, delete node_modules and npm install again, restart my laptop. but still having the same error.

```
TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this._setComponentRef.bind')

This error is located at:
in AnimatedComponent (at TouchableOpacity.js:256)
in TouchableOpacity (at LogIn.js:236)
in RCTView (at View.js:44)
in RCTView (at View.js:44)
in RCTView (at View.js:44)
in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:977)
in ScrollView (at LogIn.js:126)
in LoginScreen (created by inject-LoginScreen-with-userProfile)
in inject-LoginScreen-with-userProfile (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:388)
in NavigationContainer (at Authentication.js:22)
in Authentication (at Router/index.js:41)
in Routes (created by inject-Routes-with-userProfile)
in inject-Routes-with-userProfile (at App.js:72)
in Provider (at App.js:71)
in App (at registerRootComponent.js:17)
in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:16)
in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
in RCTView (at View.js:44)
in RCTView (at View.js:44)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

app.json:

```
{
"name": "flo",
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios",
  "eject": "expo eject"
},
"dependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
"@mindinventory/react-native-tab-bar-interaction":"github:mindinventory/react-native-tab-bar-interaction",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"expo": "^31.0.6",
"firebase": "^5.8.5",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
"react-native-app-intro-slider": "^1.0.1",
"react-native-carousel-control": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-dash": "0.0.9",
"react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.1",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
"react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
"react-native-motion": "^0.2.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.5",
"react-native-sideswipe": "^1.4.2",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
"react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^3.0.0",
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-axios-middleware": "^4.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
"babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
"jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
"mobx": "^5.9.0",
"mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
"mobx-state-tree": "^3.10.2",
"schedule": "^0.4.0"
```

}
    }

babel.config

```
module.exports = function(api) {
api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
  ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
  ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
    ]
  };
};
```

any idea how to get it run again? and why this is happening?

Comment: please post code for `AnimatedComponent`

Comment: Hi @FedeSc, i'm sorry cause i don't know where this comes from. i don't have any `AnimatedComponent`.

Comment: Please add code samples. Otherwise it's difficult help. Add the code related to `_setComponentRef`.

Comment: hi @EdisonD'souza i have update my question with some details (app.json & babel.config) . I'm using mobX syntax decorator, where i feel that cause the issue.

Comment: Please try adding `@babel/transform-flow-strip-types` plugin to your babel config.

Comment: it works!!!! oh my, thank you so much @EdisonD'souza. i install @babel/transform-flow-strip-types as your advise, then set `["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"]` as the first plugin set, in babel.config file. then everything runs.

Comment: may i know why this fixed the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding `@babel/transform-flow-strip-types` plugin to your babel config. The flow strip types plugin must go before class properties. There will be a test case that fails if you don't.

```
"plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
```